# Using an auxiliary verb "DO"

Tags: emphasis

I'm wondering if I could use "do" to make emphasis in different tenses? 
I've found examples of its using in Present Simple. So, could I use it with, for instance, other Simple tenses or, what is more interesting, with Perfect tenses? As far as I know, it just unlogical and awkward to find this verb followed by Progressive verb.

Comment: I'm pretty sure [BE] is the *only* auxiliary verb you can use with progressive / continuous verb forms (i.e. - ending in ***-ing***). And so far as I know, *all* Perfect Tense usages by definition involve the auxiliary verb [HAVE] coupled to the past participle of whatever primary verb is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**emphatic do**](http://random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2012/04/emphatic-do-does-did-and-other.html) is used with the present and past simple:

> You don't eat fish.
>   I **do** eat fish!
>
> You didn't clean your room.
>   I **did** clean my room!

The emphatic *do* isn't used with progressive tenses.  For those, we just stress the auxiliary verb that we use.

> You aren't listening.
>   I **am** listening!
>
> You won't see it.
>   I **will** see it!

And it isn't used with perfect tenses - again, we just stress the auxiliary:

> You haven't read the book.
>   I **have** read the book!
>
> You hadn't been there.
>   I **had** been there!